# javascript disabled in Mac by default?

Tags: javascript, macos

Since I dont have a Mac and dont have much experience (couldnt find any infos either)...I would like to know if Javascript in Mac is disabled by default if using Safari or any other browsers.

Im asking because it happened once that one or two users told me they couldnt access some of my sites features (all javascript) and that they are on a mac.

Comment: Users can turn javascript off, regardless of OS or browser being used.  You should always take that into account when designing a web application so that at the very least its most vital parts will work without javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works perfectly in all those browsers, essentially firefox 19-30+, Safari 4-7+, opera 15+, chrome+. They display downscaled images fine as the rendering engine improved. You can always display a fallback using SVG if rendering is ugly using javascript media queries.

Answer (score 3):

No. All of the mainstream OS X browsers support JavaScript and have it enabled by default.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see I have two downvotes. Im sorry if my question seems somehow "weak" but I couldnt find any infos on the net. 

The designs vital elements work without javascript but there are some functions which do hence why I was abit worried.